# какую нагрузку несет в себе import?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, ecmascript-6

Есть определенное веб-приложение, которое написано как множество модулей связаны между собой. Вроде бы удобно, но вопрос возник, какую себе несет нагрузка `import`, если ранее этот модуль уже был загружен в другом модуле.
P.S. Выходит так, что около 3-4 импорта во всех модулей одинаковые.

Comment: Зависит от того, где и как вы используете импорты. В браузере без ничего? Собираете бандл вебпаком? На сервере в nodejs-приложении?

Comment: @andreymal, webpack. Но также интересно в браузере "без ничего"

Comment: эм... ? возможна нагрузка сетевая или "вычислительная", какая вас беспокоит

Comment: Впрочем обе нагрузки интересны. Когда мы делаем первый импорт как я понимаю он скачивает весь файл в память и потом доступ к методам и функциям осуществляется в виде ссылок. т.е все следующие импорты не вызывают дополнительное подключение. Я правильно понимаю?